# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' - How to solve it when I even have the data and no field is None?

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I am creating a Django app. I will write the short summary of the system how it is supposed to work and then I will share my code.

When user (student) will go to the `performance_calculator.html` he/she will see a textbox where he/she will have to enter the relevant subject name. After entering the subject name, he/she will click 'Calculate' button, on the other side (server-side) the entered name will be taken and the system will search the detail (progress) of that subject of that user (student) from the Detail Model using the subject name and that user name as filters. After getting the the progress detail, each value in the detail will be assigned to a separate single variable. Those variables will be passed as parameters to `fuzz_algo()` function (a Fuzzy Logic Algorithm to calculator Performance), after getting the result, result will be forward to Client Side (Front End) using Django Messages Module.

This was the summary, now I get the error at the step when the system tries to get the progress details of the subject (whose name was entered by user) of the user (student who is using the system). and the Error is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`. I know this error happens when we receive `None` from somewhere and we try to get something from `None`. But I have populated the Detail Model along with the Subject Model using the Admin Panel (screenshots are attached). I don't know why I am getting `None` and due to `None`, this `AttributeError`.

My views.py

```
def performanceCalculator(request):
    skype = 0
    internal_course = 0
    prg_lab = 0
    mid_marks = 0
    final_marks = 0
    sub = 0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm(request.POST)

        if performance_form.is_valid():
            performance_form.save()

            sub = performance_form.cleaned_data.get('subject')
            skype = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).values().first().get('skype_session_attendance')
            internal_course = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).values().first().get('internal_course_marks')
            prg_lab = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).values().first().get('programming_lab_activity')
            mid_marks = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).values().first().get('mid_term_marks')
            final_marks = Detail.objects.filter(subject__subject=sub, user__username=User.username).values().first().get('final_term_marks')

            result = fuzz_algo(skype, internal_course, prg_lab, mid_marks, final_marks)

            messages.success(request, result)

            return redirect('performance_calculator')
    else:
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm()

    context = {
        'performance_form': performance_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/performance_calculator.html', context)
```

My models.py

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} ({})'.format(self.subject, self.user.username)


class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.OneToOneField(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skype_session_attendance = models.FloatField()
    internal_course_marks = models.FloatField()
    programming_lab_activity = models.FloatField()
    mid_term_marks = models.FloatField()
    final_term_marks = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.subject, (self.user.username)} Details'

class Sub(models.Model):
    s = models.CharField(max_length=100
```

My forms.py

```
class PerformanceCalculatorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Sub
        fields = ['subject']
```

My template (users/performance_calculator.html)

```
{% if not request.user.is_superuser and not request.user.is_staff %}
                        <div class="account-heading">
                            <h2>
                                Performance Calculator
                            </h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="content-section">
                            <form method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                <fieldset class="form-group">
                                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"></legend>
                                    {{ performance_form|crispy }}
                                </fieldset>
                                <div class="from-group">
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Calculate</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
```

This is the full error that I get:

```
AttributeError at /esacp/performance-calculator/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/esacp/performance-calculator/
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: C:\Users\khubi\OneDrive\Desktop\FYP\test_phase\users\views.py in performanceCalculator, line 61
Python Executable:  C:\environments\bsse_fyp\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\khubi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FYP\\test_phase',
 'C:\\Users\\khubi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\khubi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\khubi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\khubi\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\environments\\bsse_fyp',
 'C:\\environments\\bsse_fyp\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 14 May 2020 11:55:41 +0000
```

Now, below are the screenshots of Admin Panel showing the populated Subject and Detail model:
This is the main Django Admin Panel, see the actions at the right side?
[image]

This is the Subject Model, see 4 subjects are added, 2 of one student and 2 of other.
[image]

This is the Detail Model of one Subject of the user (student). See the details are entered and fields are not `None` or empty
[image]

Now I don't understand, why am I getting the error where there is nothing empty.

P.S. Yes, I logged in with the same user (student) whose subject detail is populated in the screenshot above. If you see in Template, I have `if condition` at start that if the user is not staff and not superuser, only then that form will be shown. So it's obvious with the Django Admin Panel logged in, i won't see that Performance Calculator form, I will only see the form if I am logged in with the regular account. But I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clarify:** By looking this time at your entire code, you have data inserted to the database already, and your form is to only perform a GET to those data ... So for performance, the form should not be saved (as it will be creating new object every time you POST). And this means that a better approach for this should be coded as a GET instead of a POST...

but lets say this is a special case and you want to do that because you want to...
This time I will directly modify your code, it is a headache at first watch because its querying too much and therefore VERY inefficient.

views.py

```
def performanceCalculator(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm(request.POST)

        if performance_form.is_valid():
            #performance_form.save() #dont save because you dont need to.
            #just process it by getting the data
            sub = performance_form.cleaned_data['subject']

            detail = Detail.objects.all().filter(user=request.user, subject=sub).first()
            #get the unique object that matches the filters
            #and I think what is causing you the Nonetype error is your queries
            #(I saw filter(subject__subject=...) and the OneToOneField doesn't 
            #behave the same as a ForeignKey and that may be the case.)

            #now fetch every field into the function
            result = fuzz_algo(detail.skype_session_attendance, detail.internal_course_marks, detail.programming_lab_activity, detail.mid_term_marks, detail.final_term_marks)

            messages.success(request, result) #if it raises int related error, include the str filter later.

            return redirect('performance_calculator')
    else:
        performance_form = PerformanceCalculatorForm()

    context = {
        'performance_form': performance_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/performance_calculator.html', context)
```

**EDIT: Forgot to add this part**

And in your models.py ... It doesn't make much sense to have the model `Subject` and it is cause to have 2 user relation...

so a cleaner model would be:

```
#removed the Subject model

class Detail(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=15) #modified to be a CharField
    skype_session_attendance = models.FloatField()
    internal_course_marks = models.FloatField()
    programming_lab_activity = models.FloatField()
    mid_term_marks = models.FloatField()
    final_term_marks = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.subject, (self.user.username)} Details'

#also the Sub class
```

**EDIT:** Add the `.first()` to get the first object on queryset

Comment: Let me try this, but I have one question. I added the model `Subject` because, I want every user to have more than one subjects. and he/she will be able to assess/calculate his/her performance of that specific subject. Will merging the `Detail` and `Subject` give the desired behavior? That means, will every user have more than one subjects and every subject having different progress detail?

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar Your Detail model is actually doing that work already, you bind the each Detail to a user using the ForeignKey Field, so each User will have it's own Detail objects, and each of those Detail objects lives the 'subject' field that has the subject name, including all the califications.

Comment: OK thanks let me try it and then I will let you know in the comment. Thank you so much by the way for putting some of your precious time in it and helping me. It was making me crazy.

Comment: Yeah, I did not forget to make migrations. Well, it is not giving me this error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'skype_session_attendance'` at the `result` statement where I am trying to get the values from the `detail` variable.

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar OHHH I FORGOT IT, put at the end of query the `.first()` because filter will return a set of objects

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar I already edited the answer with the `.first()` change, check out

Comment: OMG @Paaksing, it solved everything with which I have been struggling for days. I don't know how should I thank you, but thank you so much buddy. You have been really a great help.

Comment: @KhubaibKhawar No problem, well, ima keep going with my own codes, I think you haven't read the django docs yet, the docs will offer a lot of snippets that will actually guide you to the correct path of building the app. Well if you want to be more clever, just jump into their github and watch the source, and you will understand even better.

Comment: that's correct, I have not yet read all of the django documentation due to less time. I will read all of it soon. Thanks for the suggestion of watching the source code. BTW, again thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213921/discussion-between-khubaib-khawar-and-paaksing).

Answer (score 1):

In `forms.py`, you have set `Meta.model` as `Sub` and `Meta.fields` as `['subject']`

in `models.py`, the model `Sub` does not have a 'subject' attribute.

Comment: But in `forms.py` I have added the field `subject` by doing this statement `subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)`. Will it not create a new field? Also the details of the subjects are in Detail Model, what does it have to do with Sub Model I just created the SUb Model in order to save the input of the user from Template.

Comment: All I know is that a ModelForm is designed to represent an existing Model and its attributes. Adding an extra field to a ModelForm (as you have done) generally works, but if you include it in your ModelForm `Meta.fields` declaration, and it doesn't exist on the Model, it's likely to cause problems.